How can I place the Visual Studio HTTPS Server into the Tray Icon when I am debugging
When I am debugging my Blazor App I would like the HTTPS Server to go into the Icon tray instead of the TaskBar.  If I need to look at it, I can open it from the Icon Tray. When I am done debugging I want it to close.
Is this possible?  Thank you


I am not sure what else to write but I appreciate all the help I have received on Stack Overflow.

I found a Third Party Program that does exactly what I described in my Question.  The Server is now Running in the System Tray.  Works Beautifully.
MinimizeToTray
Note: Ensure you press ALT+F1 on the correct Windows Program.  If you misclick and press ALT+F1 on the wrong item such as the TaskBar itself you will need to Restart Windows.

Visual Studio does not have a tray icon mode and never has had one.
If you feel its a feature that is needed to be added, select the Send Feedback button on the upper right and suggest the feature.
